# Heroku: This site can’t be reached

Tags: heroku, nodes

My heroku app cannot be accessed after a build. The logs show that the web server node and worker node both are listening. 
It's a flask app run by gunicorn and it has 2 addons - newrelic and redistogo.

Error:

```
This site can’t be reached.
appname.herokuapp.com’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

Logs:

````
```2020-02-05T16:24:31.556201+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python worker.py`
2020-02-05T16:24:32.278863+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-02-05T16:24:33.363132+00:00 app[worker.1]: 16:24:33 RQ worker started, version 0.5.1
2020-02-05T16:24:33.364484+00:00 app[worker.1]: 16:24:33
2020-02-05T16:24:33.364574+00:00 app[worker.1]: 16:24:33 *** Listening on high, default, low...
2020-02-05T16:24:35.295791+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn app:server`
2020-02-05T16:24:41.159117+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-02-05T16:24:40.959907+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-05 16:24:40 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-02-05T16:24:40.961836+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-05 16:24:40 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:21126 (4)
2020-02-05T16:24:40.962097+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-05 16:24:40 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-02-05T16:24:40.971809+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-05 16:24:40 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
2020-02-05T16:24:41.143051+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-02-05 16:24:41 +0000] [20] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20```
````

**EDIT:**

Procfile:

```
web: newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn app:server
worker: python worker.py
```

Worker:

```
import os

import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(list(map(Queue, listen)))
        worker.work()
```

Comment: Please provide content of both `Procfile` and `worker.py`

Comment: Have you double checked that `appname.herokuapp.com` is correct? "appname.herokuapp.com’s server IP address could not be found." isn't likely to be an issue with your code.

Comment: Same problem was reported one week ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60183950/heroku-this-site-can-t-be-reached-dns-probe-finished-nxdomain) and it turned accessible after waiting some time. I am currently having the same issue, let's see if it get's solve alone...

Answer (score 0):

The app is accessible now. It seems to be downtime with Heroku. Although they haven't reported this in their status page.