# Heroku This site can’t be reached (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN)

Tags: node.js, heroku

Some of my personal apps and my professional apps on Heroku are not accessible. 
They don't have a custom domain linked, so I access them via http://.herokuapp.com

Most of the time, they work great, but often I receive following response from my browser

```
This site can’t be reached
<myapp>.herokuapp.com’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

The app is up and running. It does not crash (as I haven't made any changes to it in a while).
I have tried restarting all dynos, to which the log says that the app is up and running and the db is connected.

Heroku is also not reporting any of their services to being down either. 
How can I resolve this issue?

I have read a similar question, but the only result coming from it was that Heroku was temporarily down. So please don't link that one again.

**Update**
**Without any of my interference, the application can be reached again on Heroku. How is this possible if Heroku says that there were no problems with their app platforms?**
**And more important: is there a way to defend against this?**

Comment: have u tried clearing your local cache?

Comment: @RobertRowntree yes I have. Also tried the disable cache feature in Chrome.

Comment: I just deployed an app through their container registry for the first time and am getting this error. I've used Heroku for years and never seen this until now.

Comment: @JordanDodson for me, it solved itself. I contacted Heroku support a few times and they claimed they couldn't do anything about it. But after some hiccups, everything was up and running again and still is.

Comment: Same problem was reported one week ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60080313/heroku-this-site-can-t-be-reached) and it turned accessible after waiting some time.